# Return variable by socket client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have the following question. How can I return a new value to the sockets, from another JS file?

App.js

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.currentRoomId = 0;
    socket.currentRoomName = "Loading...";
    socket.currentRoomOwner = 1;
    socket.currentRoomEntry = 1.1;
});
```

RoomManager.js

```
adapter.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
    rows.forEach( (row) => { 
       socket.currentRoomId = parseInt(row.Id);
       socket.currentRoomName = row.room_name;
       socket.currentRoomOwner = row.room_owner;
       socket.currentRoomEntry = row.room_entry;
    });
});
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to `emit` and `listen` like this,

**RoomManager.js**

```
adapter.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
    rows.forEach( (row) => { 
       // emit setCurrentData with the row data
       socket.emit('setCurrentData', { data: row });
    });
});
```

**App.js**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.currentRoomId = 0;
    socket.currentRoomName = "Loading...";
    socket.currentRoomOwner = 1;
    socket.currentRoomEntry = 1.1;

    // listen to setCurrentData 
    socket.on('setCurrentData', function (row) {
       socket.currentRoomId = parseInt(row.data.Id);
       socket.currentRoomName = row.data.room_name;
       socket.currentRoomOwner = row.data.room_owner;
       socket.currentRoomEntry = row.data.room_entry;
    });
});
```